# How to add a new context menu in Adobe Reader(PDF) using C#

Tags: c#, contextmenu, adobe-reader

I'm developing an application where i need to create a new context menu item in pdf viewer (Adobe Reader). Can anyone please let me know how to create it using C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Far to vague, what viewer are you using?  The ActiveX viewer (axAcroPDF) doesn't permit doing anything like that.  The window is owned by another process, acrord32.exe.  Try killing it with Taskmgr.exe to see the effect.